# Would a fuel that is 10x more powerful output than most other fuels lead to 10x more range? or is there a different equation for this?

Tags: science-based

I have a fuel in my world that has a high output of energy than coal or gas, but does that equal a further range? Could my plane fly 10x further because of the fuel or am I just getting marginal results? Could I have a smaller fuel tank or more armor because I have more thrust?

The ultimate question is, is it a 1:1 ratio or is the ratio different?

Comment: Depends on the efficiencies. Nothing like that is ever linear. Is there a good reason you need a 10x increase in fuel energy density to correspond to exactly 10x increase in efficiency & range in your world? If not, then yeah in general better energy densities, assuming you can use them efficiently, lead to those things you mentioned. For example, nuclear power.

Comment: I would not want to be anywhere close to a container of fuel with almost 400MJ/L of energy density via oxidation…

Comment: What percentage of the weight of your plane is fuel? Can you change the shape of your wings as a result of having to carry less fule?

Comment: There's also the question of how well you can *use* that extra energy. Does it have a slow reaction rate, requiring a large burner to maintain combustion and produce a decent amount of heat? Or maybe it can't reliably be cyclically injected and ignited in a cylinder without something blowing up? You're then looking at switching from internal combustion engines back to steam engines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The math for this depends on the weight of the vehicle vs. the weight of the fuel. The larger the percentage of a vehicle is fuel, the more you'll improve performance by reducing the amount of fuel.

For ground vehicles, the differentiation really does come down to an increase in range. 25 gallons of gas is roughly equivalent to an extra passenger. It's only about 3% of the total weight of the vehicle, so a full/empty tank has a tiny impact on your miles per gallon.

A fighter jet tends to be 30% fuel. This is the point where the engineers would start making trade-offs, but there are so many factors (max range, ordinance load, loiter time, etc.) that it would be impossible to predict.

For airliners, the fuel is around 40% of the weight. This would equate to a reasonable efficiency in transport costs, but I don't know if you could actually make the planes themselves much smaller. The decrease in the size of storage for fuel will drop, but the surface area of the wings is based on the total weight. An engineer might notice the difference, but most people wouldn't.

For the Falcon 9 rocket, something around 90% of its weight is fuel. In addition to reducing fuel weight, you would also be reducing the size of the tank and hardware used to move the fuel around. This means your people would be able to leave the atmosphere much sooner in their development.